# Could not open input file: artisan

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-artisan

When trying to create a new laravel project, The following error appears on the CLI:

> Could not open input file: artisan
>
> Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error

I am using the latest version of XAMPP v3.2.1 with PHP 5.5.15 and with mcrypt enabled (made sure of that by issuing the command php -m). And I am running windows 8.1

Comment: Looks like this question is old. Did you figure out the issue? If you wouldn't mind, share the question with the rest of the squad :)

Comment: I think, php artisan is to be called from the root folder of laravel site. or else this error will popup.

Comment: You need to run your artisan command at the same level as your artisan directory. This will make sure you are in your Laravel project

Comment: Sidenote: Initially I thought that when `php artisan ...` was called, it was some sort of option for the `php` command. Turns out it refers to a file named `artisan` which is in the root of your laravel project. It should really be called `artisan.php` since it is an actual php script but the extension is omitted for brevity purposes.

Comment: Just try and execute the command in directory where all laravel code resides. Happened with me too, I was trying to run the command in project's root folder, but the code was in a sub directory

Comment: Same Issue here. I was running the command in the root folder that houses many projects. You need to run that command in the folder where the Laravel code resides for that specific project.

Comment: @Flame Thank you! I see now, it runs the php script called artisan.

Comment: make sure you have artisan.php file on root of your laravel application else you will face error like "Could not open input file: artisan".

Answer (score 513):

You need to first [create Laravel project](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation) and if you already have one you need to go to this project dir using `cd` command in terminal for example `cd myproject`.

Now you will be able to run any artisan commands, for example running `php artisan` will display you list of available commands.

Comment: This error appears when I am attempting to create a new laravel project:

cd xampp/htdocs

then

composer create-project laravel/laravel newLaravelProject

It starts to download all the required dependencies, and suddenly this error appears.

Comment: If you have moved your app folder with .env, vendor folder, config folder...etc to some where else, you may have to change directory root to this location.

Comment: This should be the selected answer. Worked perfectly!

Comment: Agreed. correct answer here.  I didn't know that it only worked from the project root folder.

Comment: I am facing an issue like this one if anyone ca help with it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64983129/cant-run-php-artisan-on-ubuntu-terminal-on-windows-10-machine

Answer (score 191):

You cannot use `php artisan` if you are not inside a `laravel` project folder.

That is why it says `'Could not open input file - artisan'`.

Comment: of course you have to do a `composer install` almost one time

Comment: I tried to make a migration from the migration folders, I hasd this message, you've got to be at the root of your application (where composer.json resides) to make it work

Comment: Right Always run php artisan command inside laravel! Its obvious, how did I forget that!

Answer (score 33):

If you project is at `/home/forge/laravel-project/`

You can properly execute your artisan like this

`php /home/forge/laravel-project/artisan ...`

Comment: In Windows you can do
`php 'E:\path\to_your_domain\artisan' october:up`

Answer (score 19):

Most probably you are not in the right directory!

Answer (score 16):

I just needed to make `artisan` executable.

`chmod +x artisan`

...and it works without the php prefix then.

Answer (score 14):

## Make Sure your current directory is your project-name

for example your project name is demo and location is f:/demo

```
f:demo> php artisan serve
```

Answer (score 11):

First, be sure to be in the laravel project folder or else the terminal won't be able to locate the `artisan` file in the project directory and any subsequent request you pulled to start a server would be rejected.

## Demo

Let's say our laravel project name is `blog` and located in `C:\laravel`
We then have: `C:\laravel\blog`

## Where to open terminal

Navigate to the `C:\laravel\blog` directory and open the command window (terminal). Input the code below:

## Laravel terminal code to start server

`php artisan serve --host 127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 6):

First create the project from the following link to create larave 7 project: [Create Project](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation)

Now you need to enter your project folder using the following command:

```
cd myproject
```

Now try to run `artisan` command, such as, `php artisan`.

Or it may happen if you didn't install compose. So if you didn't install composer then run `composer install` and try again `artisan` command.

Answer (score 5):

If it is your first install of laravel then create another directory/folder inside the laravel directory and then move to that empty folder and create another project using the command below:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

This will create a new project named "blog", then go back to parent laravel directory and now you can run this command:

```
php artisan serve
```

You will receive the return such as:

```
laravel deployment server started: http://localhost:8000
```

See attached image
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I checked out an existing Laravel project, which did not have this script. Even a `find / -name 'artisan'` produced no results. The solution turned out to be simple, if a bit weird:

```
curl -L 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/laravel/laravel/v4.2.11/artisan' > artisan
```

You probably want to choose a tagged version that matches your installed version of Laravel.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running your Laravel project in Vagrant and have just SSH-ed into the virtual machine, don't forget to `cd /vagrant` before you try running artisan commands!

Answer (score 2):

After struggling with this issue, I found out that you need to find where artisan resides by running `sudo find / -name artisan`,
and from there run the command `php artisan ....`

Answer (score 1):

This error happens because you didn't install composer on your project.

run `composer install` command in your project path.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first create Laravel project and if you already have one you need to go to this project dir using cd command in terminal for example cd myproject.

Example : C:\xampp new\htdocs\project laravel\LaravelProject>php artisan serve

Now you will be able to run any artisan commands, for example running php artisan will display you list of available commands.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Mainly this may happen because your Laravel project opens on the wrong path. Just open the folder again in your code editor. That's what happened to me when I got the same error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience, you must check if the artisan file is in your project folder. I had the same error, and when I check the artisan, it was not present.  You can easily copy any artisan file from any existing or already working project and paste it into your new project.

Or you may download it here: [artisan file](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/9.x/artisan)

Answer (score 1):

None of the solution worked for me. You can use these commands for solving the issue:

Remove bootstrap/cache/config.php file then:

```
composer dumpautoload
composer update
```

Remove vendor folder then:

```
composer install
```

If still not solved, your last option maybe to create new Laravel project:
With new folder:

```
composer create-project --force laravel/laravel my-joyful-project
```

Without new folder:

```
composer create-project --force laravel/laravel .
```

It should solve the issue. If still no, make sure you do not have older laravel version. And lastly, make sure that it is Laravel project you are working on, not Silverstripe. They are both using composer and have similar configuration files. Easy to mess up or maybe not :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I have fixed it by doing the following steps:

1. removed vendor folder `rm -Rf vendor`
2. tried to install the composer packages again: `composer install --no-dev`
3. ran the required php artisan command again

Worked!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was trying to run artisan with wrong user.
ex: the project was belonging to `fooo` user but I was `baaar` user when I run the command.
Simply changing the user or run with other user fix the problem.

##### Change to other user

```bash
sudo su - fooo
# then run the command
php artisan ...
```

##### Run with other user

```bash
sudo su - fooo php artisan ...
```

Answer (score 0):

After installing [composer](https://getcomposer.org/), you need to create the project:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel /path/to/tour/project
```

You can see the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/installation), for your php version the lastest Laravel you can install is 5.0.

Now days here is the lastest version and require > php7.0. Here is the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/installation).

Answer (score 0):

What did the trick for me was to do `cd src` from my project directoy, and **then** use the `php artisan` command, since my `artisan` file was in the `src` folder. Here is my project structure:

```
project
|__ config
|__ src
    |__ app
    |__ ..
    |__ artisan  // hello there!
    |__ ...
|__ ...
```

Answer (score 0):

if you re in say `my-project/app/somefolder` run in terminal `cd ..` two times to get in `my-project/` folder

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to note that if you have a symbolic link from a non public location which hosts your project code to say public_html - running `php artisan` in the symbolic link location (public_html) will result in this error.
You seem to need to be in the actual project directory for `php artisan` to work.

Answer (score 0):

For those people that are having the same error on cPanel terminal specifically.

Now you need to enter into your project root or public_html folder in the terminal using the following command:

**cd public_html**

Now you will be able to run any artisan commands.

**php artisan config:clear**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue. I am also in the laravel project directory. what works for me is just change the permission of the artisan file.

For linux

```
chmod 777 artisan
```

For windows

- use the file property