# "php artisan serve" command does not work in command line for Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, localhost, laravel-artisan

Is `php artisan serve` command working in command line for `laravel`?

**Step 1:**

> C:\Users\Rezaul> php artisan serve
>      Could not open input file: artisan
>   C:\Users\Rezaul>

---

**Step 2:**

> C:\Users\Rezaul>php artisan serve --port=8080
>      Could not open input file: artisan
>   C:\Users\Rezaul>

http://localhost:8000

Comment: The error indicates that the artisan file does not exist, check your root directory.

Comment: Is `C:\Users\Rezaul` place where project is?

Comment: You have to first create Laravel project into the directory where you want. Check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26193314/could-not-open-input-file-artisan

Comment: Beautify the context

Answer (score 0):

On windows you might have to give it the full path try running `php .\artisan serve`

Answer (score 0):

You should run `php artisan serve` command in You app directory like this :

```
C:\Users\Rezaul\project>php artisan serve
```

which project folder struct is like this :

```
->project\
---->app\
---->config\
---->public\
   .
   .
   .
----->artisan
----->composer.json
```

Answer (score 0):

> Could not open input file: artisan

This error message indicates that there are no file `artisan` in your current directory `C:\Users\Rezaul>`.

You should run the command in your Laravel project directory.

You should `cd` into your project directory, or right click(or with shift) in the file explorer of your project and click open cmd(or powershell) here, then run the command `php artisan serve`.