# Can't call php artisan

Tags: php, laravel

I'm setting up my Laravel environment, having installed composer and laravel. I can't call `php artisan`

I've tried **installing** and **updating**, however I'm still being returned errors.

> C:\Users\Pat\personal> php artisan PHP Warning: 
>   require(C:\Users\Pat\personal/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\Pat\personal\artisan on
>   line 18
>
> Warning: require(C:\Users\Pat\personal/vendor/autoload.php): failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\Users\Pat\personal\artisan on line 18 PHP Fatal error:  require():
>   Failed opening required 'C:\Users\Pat\personal/vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Users\Pat\personal\artisan on
>   line 18
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\Users\Pat\personal/vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Users\Pat\personal\artisan on
>   line 18 PS C:\Users\Pat\personal>

Comment: You should run `php artisan ...` commands **inside** a folder containing a Laravel project. If not, try to [create a project first](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/installation#installing-laravel)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not open input file: artisan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26193314/could-not-open-input-file-artisan)

Answer (score 1):

the **vendor folde**r is missing so you got this error:

> Warning: require(C:\Users\Pat\personal/vendor/autoload.php): failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\Users\Pat\personal\artisan on line 18

Run this command in your command prompt:

```
composer update --no-scripts 
composer update
```

- `composer update --no-scripts` It will Skips execution of scripts defined in **composer.json** file.
- `composer update` It will update your depencencies as they are specified in **composer.json** file.

With this command, you will re-create the **vendor folder** in your project

Answer (score 1):

Type on CLI:

```
composer install
```

run this command first

```
composer dump-autoload
```

source and credits to: require(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream on Synchro comment

Answer (score 0):

Check there might not vendor folder in your project root.  So first run composer install command in the terminal. And it will generate the file that are missing.

Comment: Is there vendor folder or not?