# How do I run locally?

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, phpstorm

I'm used to React and doing `npm start` to get my app running locally. However, when I run that on my new project it prompts that there is no start script. And upon further inspection, there isn't one.

If this is what my `package.json` looks like how do I get this running locally?

```
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.0",
    "axios": "^0.19",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.22",
    "datatables.net-bs4": "^1.10.22",
    "datatables.net-plugins": "^1.10.22",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^5.0.9",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.32",
    "npm": "^6.14.9",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "sass": "^1.20.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
},
"dependencies": {
    "vue-recaptcha-v3": "^1.9.0"
}
}
```

It's a Laravel environment using PHP for back end and Vue for front end. I feel really stupid for not knowing this, but when I search I'm also not finding anything.

I'm using PhpStorm, I downloaded XAMPP, Composer, and PHP. I'm not sure what I'm missing or need to do? Help, please. If I'm missing any information I can certainly provide it to the best of my ability.

[image]

I'm a dingbat, I realized I wasn't running backend. So.. I did php artisan serve and received this. Any suggestions?

```
[![enter code here][2]][2]

C:\Users\emzib\ValorSystems.com>php artisan serve
```

PHP Warning:  require(C:\Users\emzib\ValorSystems.com/vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\emzib\ValorSystems.com\artisan on line 18
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'C:\Users\emzib\ValorSystems.com/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\Users\emzib\ValorSystems.com\artisa
n:18
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
thrown in C:\Users\emzib\ValorSystems.com\artisan on line 18

Comment: A web server by the sounds of it

Comment: Are you on Windows or a linux

Comment: composer install / npm install ?

Comment: I'm on  windows - I already installed dependencies, but I can't get it to run locally.

Comment: do you have xampp or an equivalent / do you see anything when you run localhost in the browser ?

Comment: I have xampp, and if I run localhost nothing comes up

Comment: I've realized I wasn't running backend. So I did php artisan serve and got the error message I added above.

Comment: It looks like this question has the same error message:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26193314/could-not-open-input-file-artisan  It's old, but it has a lot of answers -- maybe one of those will help?

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps

1. composer install
2. npm install
3. npm run dev

Comment: It says build successful, but I'm not seeing anything beyond compiled successfully. Is it supposed to open in the browser?

Comment: It will show a URL similar to this http://localhost:8080/ open that in new browser should open it.

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a link. So no link, and nothing pops open in the browser. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: can you post the screenshot of the npm run dev command?

Comment: Just added a screenshot

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/frontend try to follow these steps

Comment: I've realized I wasn't running backend. So I did php artisan serve and got the error message I added above.